# Finding view id in Android

Tags: android

Given the following sample:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int numberOfQuantity=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
TextView quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);

    public void Increment(View view) {

        numberOfQuantity++;
        quantity.setText("" + numberOfQuantity);
    }

    public void Decrement(View view){
        numberOfQuantity--;
        quantity.setText("" + numberOfQuantity);
    }
}
```

Why can't i just use this line of code outside the method, :

```
TextView quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
```

Whenever i put this on the increment and decrement method the decrement doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The statements placed outside methods (i.e., in the declaration of the class itself) are executed during the phase of object construction. That time the activity is not bound to a layout yet, and there are no views associated with it. So, findViewByID() cannot find anything. You should call it only after setContentView(), which is called in onCreate().

Comment: thanks, what i did is i put it after the onCreate method, now the problem is it doesn't decrement why is it?

Comment: How these Increment() and Decrement() are called? Probably, they are handlers of some UI events (mouse clicks or something like this)? If so, could you show how you bind these methods to the events?

Answer (score 1):

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is inflating your layout. It creates the DOM, initialises all the classes and assigns the id's etc.

You can only call View#findViewById() once the layout is inflated.

In java, assignments are statements and statements are allowed only inside blocks of code (methods, constructors, static initializers, etc.)
Only declarations are allowed outside of these.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding calling the findViewbyId() outside the method, other answers explain very well.

for your need, try this

```
int numberOfQuantity=0;
TextView quantity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);

}


public void Increment(View view) {
    numberOfQuantity++;
    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(numberOfQuantity));
}

public void Decrement(View view){
    numberOfQuantity--;
    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(numberOfQuantity));
}
}
```

Comment: @Josel Parayno, your issue fixed?